# how many ways can I cut a stick of length n doing m cuts

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can I cut a stick of length $n$ doing $m$ cuts? $1 < m < n$

For example: with a stick of length 4, I can cut it in the following ways using 2 cuts:

[-|-|--]

[-|--|-]

[--|-|-]

Comment: replace the $-$'s with $*$'s and you have [Star and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: @YashJain Not quite ... there are $n-1$ possible cutting points, so it's ${n-1} \choose m$. Indeed for the example: $n=4$, $m=2$, and there are $3$ possible cuttings ... which is $3 \choose 2$ rather than $4 \choose 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basic stars and bars.  Very quickly:  you have $n-1$ possible cutting points, out of which you have to pick $m$. So, it's

$${n-1} \choose m$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $m$ cuts to place on a stick. I guess the cuts are indistinguishable, so there will be $n-1$ possible places where you can cut the stick, thus the total number of options will be $${{n-1}\choose{m}} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-m)! \cdot m!}$$.